# What is this symbol called

Tags: meaning

This symbol shows up when I view a pdf copy of a word document € does anyone know what it is or why.

Comment: Well, it's the symbol for the Euro currency, but what is the context in which it appears?  You should provide part of the text in which it occurs -- for all we know, it might just be a typographical error.

Answer (score 3):

It's the symbol for the [Euro Currency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euro).